# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method, A binding with matching key exists in component

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to add dagger2 in a seed project for learn pourposes (I'm not an expert), but i havving the same problem:

> e: /Users/foca/projects/personalProjects/bar-droid-application/bar-droid/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/bar/bar_droid/di/AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.bar.bar_droid.domain.repository.RegisterRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
>                   ^
>     A binding with matching key exists in component: com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.di.AccessScreenProvider_ProvideRoleSelectorFragmentFactory.RoleSelectionFragmentSubcomponent
>         com.bar.bar_droid.domain.repository.RegisterRepository is injected at
>             com.bar.bar_droid.domain.interactor.userregistration.UserRegistrationUseCase(registerRepository, …)
>         com.bar.bar_droid.domain.interactor.userregistration.UserRegistrationUseCase is injected at
>             com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.roleselector_fragment.viewmodel.RoleSelectionViewModel(…, userRegistrationUseCase)
>         com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.roleselector_fragment.viewmodel.RoleSelectionViewModel is injected at
>             com.bar.bar_droid.ui.di.ViewModelModule.provideRoleSelectionViewModel(roleSelectionViewModel)
>         java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> is injected at
>             com.bar.bar_droid.utils.mvvm.ViewModelFactory(creators)
>         com.bar.bar_droid.utils.mvvm.ViewModelFactory is injected at
>             com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.loginselector_fragment.LoginFragment.viewModelFactory
>         com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.loginselector_fragment.LoginFragment is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.bar.bar_droid.di.AppComponent → com.bar.bar_droid.di.ActivityBuilderModule_BindAccessActivity.AccessActivitySubcomponent → com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.di.AccessScreenProvider_ProvideLoginSelectorFragmentFactory.LoginFragmentSubcomponent]
>     It is also requested at:
>         com.bar.bar_droid.domain.interactor.userregistration.UserRegistrationUseCase(registerRepository, …)
>     The following other entry points also depend on it:
>         dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.bar.bar_droid.di.AppComponent → com.bar.bar_droid.di.ActivityBuilderModule_BindAccessActivity.AccessActivitySubcomponent → com.bar.bar_droid.ui.accessflow.di.AccessScreenProvider_ProvideMailPasswordFragmentFactory.MailPasswordSignUpFragmentSubcomponent]
>         dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.bar.bar_droid.di.AppComponent → com.bar.bar_droid.di.ActivityBuilderModule_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent → com.bar.bar_droid.ui.mainflow.di.MainFlowProvider_ProvideMenuFragmentFactory.MenuFragmentSubcomponent]

Here my Code:

Application:

```
class MainApplication : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Starts Dagger
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector
}
```

Dagger Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ApplicationModule::class,
        RoomDatabaseModule::class,
        FirebaseModule::class,
        GoogleModule::class,
        ActivityBuilderModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

ActivityBuilderModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [AccessScreenProvider::class, AccessScreenDependencyProvider::class])
    abstract fun bindAccessActivity(): AccessActivity

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainFlowProvider::class])
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Fragments for AccessActivity:

```
@Module
abstract class AccessScreenProvider {

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class, LoginSelectorProvider::class])
    abstract fun provideLoginSelectorFragmentFactory(): LoginFragment

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
    abstract fun provideMailPasswordFragmentFactory(): MailPasswordSignUpFragment

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class, RoleSelectionProvider::class])
    abstract fun provideRoleSelectorFragmentFactory(): RoleSelectionFragment
}
```

ViewModelModule:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)

@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @PerFragment
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun provideLoginViewModel(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @PerFragment
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MailPasswordSignUpViewModel::class)
    abstract fun provideMailPasswordSighUpViewModel(mailPasswordSignUpViewModel: MailPasswordSignUpViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @PerFragment
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(RoleSelectionViewModel::class)
    abstract fun provideRoleSelectionViewModel(roleSelectionViewModel: RoleSelectionViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

And finally for RoleSelectionProvide:

```
@Module
class RoleSelectionProvider {

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    fun provideRealAuthDataSource(fireBaseAuth: FirebaseAuth): UserAuthDataSource = RealUserAuthDataSource(fireBaseAuth)

    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    fun provideRegisterRepository(realUserAuthDataSource: RealUserAuthDataSource, userProfileDao: UserProfileDao): RegisterRepository {
        return RegisterRepositoryImpl(realUserAuthDataSource, userProfileDao)
    }
}
```

The only place that I'm injecting **RegisterRepositoryImpl** is on **UserRegistrationUseCase**, I don't have any idea about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is strange that you are using in two places: ViewModelModule. It is most probably the problem and the duplication of keys error. "A binding with matching key exists in component:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that you are using it in two places: ViewModelModule. It is most probably the problem and the duplication of keys error. "A binding with matching key exists in component:"

Also in provideMailPasswordFragmentFactory you are passing only ViewModelModule, but in 
provideRoleSelectorFragmentFactory you are passing both ViewModelModule and also RoleSelectionProvider. In the first case, you are missing the dependencies provided by RoleSelectionProvider which provides the Repository.

```
    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
    abstract fun provideMailPasswordFragmentFactory(): MailPasswordSignUpFragment

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class, RoleSelectionProvider::class])
    abstract fun provideRoleSelectorFragmentFactory(): RoleSelectionFragment
```

Comment: your comments took me some time at understand 100% related to my code. But finally I undertood the problem, in ViewModelModule i had all the @Binds for ViewModels. But as you mentions that culd be a problem, finally i separated in several modules, providing at each fragment the specific module and.....works.


Thanks you a lot, this problem took my a lot of time